# Translating x,y while scaling

Tags: c++, allegro5, cartesian-coordinates

I'm trying to graph x,y coordinates where the window size is 600px by 600px. (0,0) would be in the top left.
(300,300) middle of the window.
(600,600) would be in the bottom right.
I am trying to translate latitude/longitude in radians to pixels and then plotting them.
I'm calculating 1px = ? lat by

```
`fabs(lborder+rborder)/600`
```

I calculated lon by taking the top and bottom borders.
Then when I want to find a specific position for a specific lat or lon:

```
lat/(previous # calculated above)
```

Problem is my window goes from 0,0 to 600,600 as explained above and I can get negative points and I'm not sure how to move them and I don't know how to center them around 300,300 when the bounds change.

At the moment, as long as I make the center (0,0) in terms of (x,y), not pixels, points get plotted where they're supposed to go.
For example, if x is -1 to 1 and y is -3 to 3, (300px,300px) would be (0,0).

If I change the bounds to say x -.5 to 1 and y -3 to .5, (300px,300px) would be (.25, 1.25). However, the calculations above with these numbers.

```
1.5/600 = .0025 ----> 1px = .0025lat.
3.5/600 = .0058 ----> 1px = .0058lon.
```

Then taking the midpoint (.25,1.25):

```
.25/.0025 = 100px
1.25/.0058 = 215px
```

which is clearly not 300px,300px despite being the center of the graph.

Any ideas would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You should expand your question. Maybe give an example image with what you have and what you want would help.

Comment: I recommend shifting lat/lon from [-PI/2;PI/2] into [0;PI] to match positive values only. This way a simple conversion into window coordinates is possible

Comment: @MABVT I'm not sure I understand how to do that. Can you give an example?

Comment: You have a value in Radians which is im the interval [-PI,PI] (-180°,180°) for longitude and [-PI/2,PI/2] (-90°,90°) for latitude. Shift longitude to (0,360) i.e. [0,2PI] and latitude to (0,180) or [0,PI] by applying the appropriate formula (I'll leave this to you as a food for thought). Then you can map these into screencoords [0,600]

Comment: If my answer was useful, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to adjust the coordinates to the center, then maybe somthing like this?

```
Coord coordsFromCenter(Coord old_coord, float height, float width)
{
    Coord new_center;

    float new_x_center = width/2.0;
    float new_y_center = height/2.0;

    new_center.set_x(old_coord.get_x() - new_x_center);
    new_center.set_y(old_coord.get_y() - new_y_center);

    return new_center;
}
```