# Translating axes while changing bounds

Tags: c++, allegro5, cartesian-coordinates

So I understand to translate:

```
x = x' + x0     or     x' = x - x0
y = y' + y0     or     y' = y - y0
```

where (x,y) are old coordinates relative to xy system, (x',y') are new coordinates relative to x'y' system, and (x0,y0) are coordinates relative to old xy system.

I'm looking to translate a system while also changing the bounds. I want to "zoom in" on a particular section of a graph within a fixed window, which would change the origin and the bounds.

For reference, I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953674/translating-x-y-while-scaling?noredirect=1), but I think it was a little more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this answers your question:

Let's assume the window that you are plotting at (in pixel coordinate) is such that the lower-left corner is `(p_ll, q_ll)` and the upper-right corner is `(p_ur, q_ur)`.

In your Cartesian coordinate, however, the same locations are `(x_ll, y_ll)` and `(x_ur, y_ur)`. Then these are the transformations you need:

```
p(x) = p_ll + (p_ur - p_ll) * (x - x_ll) / (x_ur - x_ll)
q(y) = q_ll + (q_ur - q_ll) * (y - y_ll) / (y_ur - y_ll)
```

So, for example, in case that the window is `x from 0 to 600 and y from 0 to 600`, and the plot bounds are `x from -2 to 2 and y from -1 to 1` then a point that has a coordinate of `(0.0, 0.0)` is going to be at `(p(0), q(0))` or

```
p(0.0) = 0 + (600 - 0) * (0 -(-2)) / (2 - (-2)) = 300
q(0.0) = 600 + (0 - 600) * (0 - (-1)) / (1 - (-1)) = 300
```

same for any other point. You can try the equation and you should find that `p(-2) = 0`, `p(2) = 600`, `q(-1) = 600`, and `q(1) = 0`.

Note that I'm here assuming pixel y coordinate is pointing down (as almost all monitor coordinates do) while the Cartesian coordinate y is pointing up.

If you want to go from screen coordinate to plot coordinate (for example if you want to convert the position of a mouse click to its Cartesian counter-part) then use these inverse transformations:

```
x(p) = x_ll + (x_ur - x_ll) * (p - p_ll) / (p_ur - p_ll)
y(q) = y_ll + (y_ur - y_ll) * (q - q_ll) / (q_ur - q_ll)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems that this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how and why those transformations work? Or maybe a link to a page explaining it?

Comment: Both of them are equations of lines that pass through two points, and the two points are the known coordinates of the two corners in both screen and plot. So we know `(pll, qll)` is supposed to be converted to `(xll, yll)` and `(pur, qur)` to `(xur, yur)`. Now, any other value that we choose for `x` or `y` has a counter part in `p` and `q` that is on the line that passes through those two points.

Comment: You even don't have to use the two corners that I mentioned. For example, you can even use one of the corners and the center, or center and the width and height of the window, but over all the transformations are just linear interpolations :-)